# Gnuplot png on ubuntu

Tags: gnuplot

So, I'm using the following code to plot data from a file called "p2.txt":

```
reset
set terminal png 
set size square
set pm3d map
set xrange[0:100]
set yrange[0:100]
set dgrid3d 100,100
do for [i=1:1]{
set output sprintf("a%03.0f.png",i)
splot 'p2.txt' u 1:2:3 every :::(0+i*100)::(100+i*100)
}
```

So here is the result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq5Ae.png)

I don't know why or how, but it seems that a part of the gnuplot code is being written over the image, why is that? How do I get rid of this?
I use Ubuntu 16.04 x64 and gnuplot 4.6.

Comment: Just adding, here is the file(p2.txt) I used: https://file.io/xSHyBp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the automatic plot key. Use `unset key` or `splot ... title ""` to remove it.

Comment: Worked for me, I'm ashamed it was this simple, thank you very much for your help and attention!